# Oracle XSLT processor(s)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, xslt

I am confused by the relation between the Java XSLT processor included in Oracle's XDK and the XSLT processor embedded in Oracle's DB and used by the SQL XMLtransform function.

Are these the same beast which therefore have the same features and level of support of XSLT 2.0 or are they two different implementations which may have different features?

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr/25245033#25245033

Comment: Executed within Oracle (with XMLTransform), that gives "Oracle corporation" for the vendor and "1.0" for the version. I haven't tested it with the XDK yet...

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle XDK was developed independently by Oracle before their acquisition of Sun. It is not the same as the technology in the JDK. I don't know what is embedded in Oracle DB but I suspect it is the XDK or something with the same original codebase.

As far as I'm aware XSLT 2.0 support in the XDK processor was never completed.

Incidentally the XSLT processor in the JDK is different from Apache Xalan as well, though in this case they have common origins. But in that case it's murky because Apache Xalan actually contains technology from two different original processors, LotusXSL from Lotus/IBM, and XSLTC from Sun, and I don't know how much of this is also in the JDK.

Oracle, last time I checked, also has at least one product with Saxon inside, probably the accidental consequence of an acquisition.

Comment: Yes, I would guess that the implementation in the XDK is the one that was pushed by Steve Muench when he was an "XML evangelist" at Oracle. The [documentation of the XDK](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDK/adx_ref_standards.htm#ADXDK2400) states that it supports XPath/XSLT 2.0 WD dated 04 April 2005. Within Oracle, if I try a function such as `normalize-unicode()` which was already introduced in that WD, I get an error, so my guess would be that it is not using the same processor as the XDK... I'll try to double check to confirm that!

Comment: Actually, the page you cite says the XDK supports the 2005 draft of 2.0 partially. Features omitted include regex support, format-date/time, tunnel parameters, use-when...